# Convolution of a 2d array in one direction [R]

Tags: arrays, r, convolution

Is there any function in R to do the following procedure on a 2d array?

assume that I have an array like:

```
0    0    0    1    0    1
1    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    1    0    1    0
0    1    0    0    1    1
```

I want to do a linear convolution on this array in Horizontal direction, or with more detail I want a function to shift the array horizontally (with adding zeros) and dot product it to the main array and sum up all the elements of the resulting array.

so the result will be a linear vector

in this example the result will be:

```
0,2,1,2,1,9,1,2,1,2,0
```

for example, the second number which is 2, is the result of dot producting the main matrix with a copy of just 2 last columns as columns 1 and 2 (with other zero padding for the remaining columns) and sum all the resulting elements together:

```
0    0    0    1    0    1
1    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    1    0    1    0
0    1    0    0    1    1
```

element-wise product to:

```
0    1    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
1    0    0    0    0    0
1    1    0    0    0    0
```

results in:

```
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    1    0    0    0    0
```

and finally by summing all elements it results in =2

Comment: Your description is still a bit unclear. Do you mean pointwise matrix multiplication like `sum(m1 * m2)`? Then I'd expect 1 instead of 2 for the second number.

Comment: @tonytonov thanks for mentioning, i edited the post. please read again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function, but the main idea is quite straightforward:

```
shift <- function(m) {
    cbind(m[, -1], rep(0, nrow(m)))
}

shifted_prod <- function(m) {
    mm <- m
    val <- numeric(ncol(m))
    for (i in 1:ncol(m)) {
        m <- shift(m)
        val[i] <- sum(m * mm)
    }
    val
}

shifted_prod(m)
#[1] 1 2 1 1 0 0
```

I still don't understand how you expect 2 as a result (element [4, 2] is 1, all others are 0). You can add `print` statements to watch the `for` loop step by step.

You'll probably want something like `rev(val)` in the end (see for yourself), since right now `val[k]` is the result obtained by shifting the original matrix `k` times.

Comment: thanks, i implemented a function myself but I'm looking if there is any special fast implementation... thanks for your code

Comment: You're welcome. If by fast you mean real fast, maybe you should take the Rcpp route. Another optimization hint would be to replace elements in-place, without copying matrices (i.e. no `cbind`, no reassignment).